# I'm trying to convert Object to Array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, ecmascript-6

Here is the one object:

```
const language = {
  fluency: {
    "English": "Advanced",
    "French": "Intermediate"
  },
  read: ["English", "French"],
  speak: ["English"],
  write: ["English"]
};
```

And I'm trying transform into array of object like:

```
const newLanguage = [
    {
        language: "English",
        fluency: "Advanced",
        read: true,
        speak: true,
        write: true,
    },
    {
        language: "French",
        fluency: "Intermediate",
        read: false,
        speak: false,
        write: false,
    }
]
```

Here is the result what I have tried:

```
var values = Object.entries(language).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))
```

And it's result is:

```
[
  { fluency: { English: 'Advanced', French: 'Intermediate' } },
  { read: [ 'English', 'French' ] },
  { speak: [ 'English' ] },
  { write: [ 'English' ] }
]
```

P.S
I'm not asking for the code, but if any one could give me a steps to transform into a result would be a great help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the spread operator and separate fluency from other properties and then use `.map()` to build an array of objects based on extracted fluency values. [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be used to build an object based on the properties from `rest` variable:

```js
const language = {
  fluency: {
    "English": "Advanced",
    "French": "Intermediate"
  },
  read: ["English", "French"],
  speak: ["English"],
  write: ["English"]
};


let {
  fluency,
  ...rest
} = language;

let result = Object.entries(fluency).map(([lang, flue]) =>
  Object.keys(rest)
  .reduce((obj, skill) => {
    obj[skill] = rest[skill].includes(lang);
    return obj;
  }, {
    language: lang,
    fluency: flue
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Appreciate for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```js
const language = {
  fluency: {
    "English": "Advanced",
    "French": "Intermediate"
  },
  read: ["English", "French"],
  speak: ["English"],
  write: ["English"]
};

const newLanguage = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(language.fluency)) {
  newLanguage.push({
        language: key,
        fluency: value,
        read: language.read.includes(key),
        speak: language.speak.includes(key),
        write: language.write.includes(key),
    });
}

console.log(newLanguage);
```

Comment: Appreciate for the help! :)